# What is the url for http telemetry, in the Thingsboard micro service architecture?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I am implementing a system using thingsboard msa (micro service architecture) to achieve high availability and fault tolerance. But I cannot pass telemetry data to the http transport layer.

I am using the released version on thingsboard github https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/tree/master/docker

I tried using HAproxy ip  but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone know which ip and port i should use?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED
this version: https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/tree/master/docker not have the transport configurations and logback.xml.